# Passing a PHP variable to JavaScript to use in jQuery.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'd like to pass a variable from `PHP` to `JavaScript` to use it inside my `jQuery.ajax`-call. I've tried a lot of things now, but without success.

Here is my current code:

```html
$( document ).ready(function() {
    function getLog() {
        ms = Date.now();
        var chatlink = "<?php echo $clink; ?>";

        $.ajax({
            url: chatlink+ms,
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(text) {
                $("#chat").text(text, "<br />");
                setTimeout(getLog, 500); // refresh every half second
            }
        })
     }
         
         
// some more code here


<?php $clink = 'foo.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Move `<?php $clink = 'foo.php'; ?>` up before you echo it in the javascript.

Comment: Have you used viewed the source code of the page or checked the browser console for errors? Viewing the source code or inspect element & trace back to the JS it should show you how the `php` is outputting and the console should display errors if one does occur.

Comment: is this inside a php file? if not it won't work.

Comment: it is in a php file and...yeah, the correct placement got the work. Thank you guys :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i pass a php variable to ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26862509/how-can-i-pass-a-php-variable-to-ajax)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## How to pass PHP variables to JavaScript

*Recommendation:*

Deploy the content you must generate with PHP as global variables and use them in your scripts to keep your source code clean.

---

### HTML in PHP file

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
$foo     = 'bar';                          #1
$arr_foo = array( 'bar', 'baz', 'blong' ); #2
$arr_js           = array();               #3 | start collection
$arr_js['foo']    = $foo;                  #3 | extend collection ...
$arr_js['arrFoo'] = $arr_foo;              #3
$arr_js['null']   = null;                  #3
$arr_js['bool']   = true;                  #3
$arr_js['int']    = 0;                     #3
$arr_js['float']  = 0.123;                 #3

echo "<script>

/* make sure to declare your name space if you haven't already */
window.yourApp = window.yourApp || {};

/* #1 deploy your PHP variable as markup
don't forget to wrap variables properly if nessecary */
window.yourApp.foo = '$foo';

/* #2 if you are not sure if the PHP variable contains signs that must be escaped 
or have a non primitive type such as arrays then JSON is there to the rescue */
window.yourApp.arrFoo = " . json_encode( $arr_foo ) . ";

/* #3 if you have a lot of vars that you want to transfer to your JS you could
also collect them in an assoziative array and then deploy them all in one
as described above */
window.yourApp = " . json_encode( $arr_js ) . "; /* most convenient way IMHO */

console.log( window.yourApp );

</script>";
```

### JavaScript file

```
console.log( window.yourApp );
```

---

*How to get PHP variables via ajax?*

### JSON encoded PHP array in PHP file

```
<?php $arr_js = array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'arrFoo' => array( 'bar', 'baz', 'blong' ),
    'null' => null,
    'bool' => true,
    'int' => 0,
    'float' => 0.123,
    'two way magic :)' => $_POST['yourApp']['coming from sender']
);
echo json_encode( $arr_js );
// lets assume the name of this file is "ajax-json.php"
```

### JavaScript file

```
// must be located in the same directory as "ajax-json.php" in this setup
// make sure jQuery is available!
jQuery.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax-json.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {yourApp: {'coming from sender': 'pure awesomeness'}},
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response )
    }
})
```

---

#### References

- [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
- [JSON](http://www.json.org/json-en.html)
- [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

---

*The explanations above are actually an edit!*

See snippet below which is the original answer that is marked as accepted.

```html
<!-- HTML in a PHP file -->
<?php $clink = 'foo.php'; ?>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    function getLog() {
        ms = Date.now();
        var chatlink = "<?php echo $clink; ?>";

        $.ajax({
            url: chatlink+ms,
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(text) {
                $("#chat").text(text, "<br />");
                setTimeout(getLog, 500); // refresh every half second
            }
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This did the trick. I should have watched for this simple mistakes at first :D

Comment: @Rhabdomyolyse also consider the edit in my answer... (if you like to)